# jQuery: Not able to restrict “number”-only input for textboxes in Android chrome

Tags: jquery

Input field is taking alphabets along with numerics. Which should not be the case.

I'm using the following code. Which is helpful in all other browsers other than "Android Chrome" browser.

```
var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode

    if ((keycode > 47 && keycode < 58) || (keycode == 46 || keycode == 8) || (keycode == 9 || keycode == 13) || (keycode == 37 || keycode == 39)) {

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself from a head ache by adding `type="number"` attribute to the `<input>`

```
<input type="number" />
```

Note that this is HTML 5.

Comment: I tried adding this, I'm getting up and down scroll format. Which I should not get and its not solving the purpose though. Android chrome is still taking the alphabets. I tried pattern=[0-9]*, it didnt work.